# Placement of variables in a correlation

Tags: grammar

Lung cancer correlates with smoking.
Smoking correlates with lung cancer.

Are both correct or does one have to worry about which one is the dependent variable (lung cancer) and which one is the independent variable (smoking)?

Comment: Sounds like a question for [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Typically one phrases correlations as: There is a high degree of correlation *between* lung cancer and smoking.

Comment: 1. Jim's right. Or: LC & S are correlated. Or LC & S correlate.

Answer (score 2):

"[Correlation does not imply causation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation)" and if your listener understands that then you can use it in either order.  From [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/552/):

[image]

But if they do not understand, and instead think *correlates with* is similar to *is caused by*  then you might try to put what you think is the effect before the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. Wolfram MathWorld defines *[correlation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Correlation.html)* as

> ...the degree to which two or more quantities are linearly associated.

Perhaps you are concerned that the order in which you talk about the variables will alter their correlation. MacMillan Dictionary's definition of *[correlation](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/correlation)* may clarify:

> **correlation**: a connection or relationship between two or more things that is not caused by chance. A positive correlation means that
>   two things are likely to exist together; a negative correlation means
>   that they are not

*Smoking correlates with lung cancer* and *lung cancer correlates with smoking* are positive correlations in either case. If you smoke, it's more likely that you will develop lung cancer; if you have lung cancer, it's much more likely that you were or are a smoker.